# C# how to access variables without creating an intance?

Tags: c#, class, variables, instance

This is what I wanted to do:

```
public class Worker
{
    public int wage;

    public void pay()
    {
        Economy.money -= this.wage;
        // I want the money(of the economy) to be subtracted by the wage of the worker.
    }
}

public class Economy
{
    public int money;
}
```

I would like it if I could have more than 1 economy.

So I want the money of the economy (which the worker belongs to) to be subtracted by the wage of the worker.

How do I do this?

Comment: I thin you have to try stuff before posting your homework here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more than one economy, then you need a property that keeps track of which economy each worker belongs to. Then you can just use that reference to subtract the wage from the correct economy:

```
public class Worker {

    public Economy InEconomy { get; private set; }
    public int Wage { get; private set; }

    // set the econdomy and wage in the constructor
    public Worker(Economy economy, int wage) {
        this.Wage = wage;
        this.InEconomy = economy;
    }

    public void Pay() {
        InEconomy.money -= this.Wage;
    }
}

public class Economy {
    public int money;
}
```